# in which programming languages can we develop applications for adobe air?

Tags: air

In which programming languages  can we develop applications for adobe air ? java ?

Comment: No, java is not a supported language.

Answer (score 4):

You can use HTML & AJAX (HTML is a **markup language** and AJAX utilises **JavaScript**) or you can use **ActionScript** from within Adobe Flash and Adobe Flex.

[Adobe AIR Developer Centre](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/)

Answer (score 2):

ActionScript
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/

Answer (score 1):

Air is in fact a "non-web web browser".  IOW, the runtime has WebKit (HTML+SVG+JavaScript) + Flash (ActionScript 3 + Flex library); but instead of an URL field to type an address, it opens a downloaded package.

So, to answer your question:

- you can write as a modern Ajax-Heavy web app; with the advantage of not having to support a variety of browsers.
- you can write Flash applications, either with or without Flex; which is a nice GUI library.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to develop RIA application is [Adobe Flex](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/flex/)
You can see some RIA application in [Tour de Flex](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex/)